# RPi 0W: some GPIO pins apparently not working

Tags: gpio, hardware

I have a Raspberry Pi 0 W, connected with both a [WaveShare Battery HAT](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/Li-ion_Battery_HAT) and a [WaveShare 1.44" LCD screen](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/1.44inch_LCD_HAT#Datasheet) with joystick and three buttons.

The screen works, the joystick works partially and the three buttons do not work at all.

The hardware uses SPI, five GPIO pins for the joystick and three GPIO pins for the three button keys.

I see GPIO pins GPIO.21 and GPIO.22 (physical pins 29 and 31) at V=1 using command-line `gpio` command, and if I move the joystick up or left, they do change to V=0 as expected.

This does not happen for the other GPIOs, which are shown as V=0 by `gpio`; therefore the software "sees" e.g. the keys as permanently pressed.

Since I soldered the GPIO header myself, my first hypothesis was a massive soldering fault. I verified that the resistance between the PCB pins of button 1 is above 4 MOhm with button at rest, decreases to zero when button is pressed. Resistance between + pin of button 1 and LCD HAT header is zero as expected. Resistance between LCD HAT header and Pi solder pad is also zero. This is physical pin 40 on the header, or GPIO.29, but `gpio` doesn't see it at all.

But I can't see what could explain the Pi seeing *two* pins and not seeing *others*. The initialization routine is the same for all the pins, so [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/36984/python-gpio-not-reading-inputs) *should* not apply.

I have checked a possible interference between the two HATs by checking their schematics on the WaveShare Wiki; no joy. Nobody else seems to have had this problems on the forums, which tells me it isn't a software issue. The same problem emerges using `gpio`, Python and the C source.

The physical position on the board *could* be a red herring, and yet...

The same code *does* work flawlessly on a Raspberry Pi 3B *without* the battery HAT, but this has lots of possibility of actually being a red herring since OS, configuration and power supply are all different. Also, on the full Pi I have installed *lots* of libraries and code in the past months, so the WaveShare autoconfigure creates a different binary, which *doesn't run at all* if I copy it on the Zero (an issue for another day).

At this point I have to provisionally conclude that either my Pi is badly broken - *only* in the GPIO section (!) - **or that I forgot to check/setup something *really* basic**.

So, I'm posting a question - I've found that whenever I forget something really stupid, it immediately pops on my mind as soon as I make myself ridiculous by asking for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, the lightbulb went off as expected. *What if...?*

So first I tried running a Python test *explicitly setting the GPIO pin to pull-up* to verify if this is, under the hood, a duplicate of [the question I had referred](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/36984/python-gpio-not-reading-inputs) and there's simply some software issue on top of that.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(36, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)    
try:
    while True:
        print GPIO.input(36)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

and lo and behold!, **now button 3 works**. So *why doesn't the sample program?*

I checked on [BCM2835 library](https://www.airspayce.com/mikem/bcm2835/input_8c-example.html), and found how to do this in C language

```
// Set RPI pin P1-15 to be an input
bcm2835_gpio_fsel(PIN, BCM2835_GPIO_FSEL_INPT);
//  with a pullup
bcm2835_gpio_set_pud(PIN, BCM2835_GPIO_PUD_UP);
```

So in the end **I found a bug in the WaveShare Raspberry code**, precisely in `obj/DEV_Config.c`, where it *doesn't* set the pin to pull-up, but only when the BCM2835 library is used (WiringPi apparently would have worked).

```
void DEV_GPIO_Mode(UWORD Pin, UWORD Mode)
{
#ifdef USE_BCM2835_LIB
    if(Mode == 0 || Mode == BCM2835_GPIO_FSEL_INPT){
        bcm2835_gpio_fsel(Pin, BCM2835_GPIO_FSEL_INPT);
    }else {
        bcm2835_gpio_fsel(Pin, BCM2835_GPIO_FSEL_OUTP);
    }
#elif USE_WIRINGPI_LIB
    printf("Pin %d using WIRINGPI\n", Pin);
    if(Mode == 0 || Mode == INPUT){
        pinMode(Pin, INPUT);
        pullUpDnControl(Pin, PUD_UP);
    }else{
        pinMode(Pin, OUTPUT);
        // printf (" %d OUT \r\n",Pin);
    }
```

Armed with this knowledge, I modified the file and re-ran `make`

```
if(Mode == 0 || Mode == BCM2835_GPIO_FSEL_INPT){
    bcm2835_gpio_fsel(Pin, BCM2835_GPIO_FSEL_INPT);
    // Set GPIO pin to pull-up
    bcm2835_gpio_set_pud(Pin, BCM2835_GPIO_PUD_UP);
}
```

...and *now* it works.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.